# Is using past perfect in if clause correct in an imaginary situation?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, past-simple, conditionals

I heard this sentence in a TV show:

> "If I *would have gone back in time* and did everything from the beginning, I would have given...".

Based on my knowledge when something is imaginary (like going back in time), I should use simple past in the if sentence. So, shouldn't that sentence be like this?

> If I *went back in time* and did everything from the beginning, I would have given...

Is there a difference between the meaning of the two sentences?

Answer (score 2):

When talking about something that didn’t happen in the past, many English speakers use the conditional perfect (if I would have done) when they should be using the past perfect (if I had done). The error is often, but not exclusively, perpetrated by US speakers.

See here

[English mistakes - if I would have](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/english-mistakes/if-i-would-have/)